# Should I downvote code-only answers? (How should I handle them)

Tags: discussion, answers, downvote-reason

First here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662331/storing-a-dictionary-in-swift-in-permanent-storage/28662448) my question is about.

The first answer was first a code-only answer. I saw the answer and gave it a down-vote, followed by an explanation, that it doesn't make sense to show a snippet only without the explanation what was actually wrong with my code.

After that, there was a bit of a debate about why I've downvoted etc.(Read the comments on the answer).

Now my question: Was it okay in this scenario, to downvote the answer even if the code was working and it was only because of the lack of explanation or is it fine?

Also I'm a bit disgruntled because of that discussion, if I'm honest. :)